# Extending continuous maps from spheres to Euclidean spaces

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Fix $d\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the following sets as topological spaces with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.
$$S^d = \{ (x_0,\ldots,x_d)\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1}\mid \sum x_i^2 = 1\}$$ $$ D^{d+1} = \{ (x_0,\ldots,x_d)\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1}\mid \sum x_i^2 \leq 1\}.$$

Is it true that for every continuous map $f:S^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$, there is a continuous map $g:D^{d+1}\to\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $g|_{S^d}\equiv f$, and $g(D^{d+1})\subseteq f(S^d)$?

Comment: The Hopf map $S^3\to S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ doesn't have such a g, otherwise it would be homotopically trivial, which it isnt.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Every map into $\mathbb{R}^3$ is homotopically trivial regardless of its domain.

Comment: In fact every map $f:S^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R^d}$ extends over $D^{d+1}$. The condition $g(D^{d+1})\subseteq f(S^d)$ will not be possible in general.

Comment: @Tyrone, Otis was referring to the nontriviality of the Hopf map to the sphere. This obstructs a filling of the form desired by the OP

Comment: @PhilTosteson As the OP is considering maps to $\mathbb{R}^d$, that does not obstruct a filling of the form that is sought.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So as I understand it, the Hopf map can be extended, but the image of $g$ can never be contained in the image of $f$. This is a counterexample when d=3, the OP obviously holds for d=0,1, what about d=2?

Comment: @OtisChodosh why not to make an answer from you comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, here is my comment in answer form:

This fails for $d=3$. The [Hopf map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) $f : S^3\to S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be homotoped (through maps to $S^2$) to a constant map. The existence of $g : D^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $g(D^4)\subset f(S^3) = S^2$ would precisely be such a homotopy.

---

For $d=2$ the question asks if a map $f:S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ can always be homotoped to a trivial map inside of its image. I think the answer to this is "yes" it can: Ian Agol's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/189327/1540) points to a paper of [Cannon-Conner-Zastrow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189323/can-a-subset-of-the-plane-have-nontrivial-h-2-or-pi-2#:%7E:text=Cannon%2DConner%2DZastrow) proving that $\pi_2(f(S^2)) = 0$. This yields the desired homotopy.

---

(Of course, as pointed out in the comments, for $d=1$ a continuous map $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ has an interval as an image, and thus is homotopically trivial in its image.)